# Getting call history in an iPhone application without the intention of putting it on the Apple Store

Tags: iphone

I need to access the call history in an iPhone app.
I know there is no way to do that and if you want to publish your application in the Apple Store,but I don't need that.

I want to know if I can read the /var/mobile/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db file using the apple sdk or any third party API. I remark I don't need to put the application on the Apple Store. Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: If you really want to know - why not try yourself first?

Comment: Because I am waiting for an apple license and as far as I know on the simulator doesn't have the call_history.db file.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to put it on the app store, you can do whatever you like. Bear in mind you're not going to be able to read the call history DB file unless the device is jailbroken *whatever* you're trying to do: apps run in sandboxes, and unless you jailbreak you're simply not going to be able to get access to that data.

Comment: Ty lxt.So you mean without putting the application in de app store you can do whatever you like(for example an application that has content Apple doesn't allow,etc),but accessing the call history DB file is not possible if you don't jailbreak(using the Apple SDK or any third party API),don't you?.I plan to install my app in the iPhone using the ad-hoc feature the Apple "company" license includes,so I thought I didn't need to jailbreak the iphone(jailbreaking the iphone is something I could do in my iPhone but not on the iPhones where the app is going to be used finally).Do you think I'm right?

Comment: You need to jailbreak the phone because otherwise iOS is going to lock your app down and you won't be able to read the file. You can write whatever code you want if you're not going on the app store - but there's no guarantee that code will work. In this case, you're trying to read a file that's outside of the application sandbox. Unless you're jailbroken, iOS won't let you do that.

Comment: Ok. In other words, what prevent you access the call_history.db file is the iOS,not Apple when they accept or deny your app,doesn't it?

Comment: sorry but that comment was incomplete.My idea is if Apple can access this data(you can see your last calls on the phone) maybe it is possible to access via a 3th party API(Free Tool Chain or something),don't know,just asking.I am thinking also in getting the calls using core telephony framework(I don't need the numbers,only the hour/date).thank you very much for your comments.

Comment: Core Telephony doesn't give you call history. You won't be able to access files outside your app sandbox unless you're jailbroken. Simple as, I'm afraid.